# No visible @interface for 'CompCost' declares the selector

Tags: objective-c

Really new to this and can't find any solution to this problem

An

```
" No visible @interface for 'CompCost' declares the selector " occurs here 
logicForCompCost setAmountTermin:costTermin and for the whole segment
```

I have a simillar solution in another logic, here it works fine.

CompPost.m

```
#import "CompCost.h"
#import "AssEmployeeCost.h"
#import "EmplyeeCost.h"
#import "ResearchCost.h"

@implementation CompCost

-(void) AddAllCompanyCostInformation:(NSNumber *) costTermin
                     withTotalITCost:(NSNumber *) costIT
                   withTotalTeleCost:(NSNumber *) costTele
                  withTotalCleanCost:(NSNumber *) costClean
                     withTotalElCost:(NSNumber *) costEl
                   withTotalSuppCost:(NSNumber *) costSupp
                   withTotalElseCost:(NSNumber *) costElse;
 {

    CompCost *logicForCompCost = [[CompCost alloc]init];

    [logicForCompCost setAmountTermin:costTermin];
    [logicForCompCost setAmountIT:costIT];
    [logicForCompCost setAmountTele:costTele];
    [logicForCompCost setAmountClean:costClean];
    [logicForCompCost setAmountEl:costEl];
    [logicForCompCost setAmountSupp:costSupp];
    [logicForCompCost setAmountElse:costElse];

    if (!_totalCostComp) {
        _totalCostComp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    }

    [_totalCostComp addObject:logicForCompCost];

}
@end
```

and CompCost.H

```
//
//  CompCost.h
//  Signium International
//
//  Created by Simon Z. Kaczmarek on 09/12/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Simon Z. Kaczmarek. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CompCost : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray* totalCostComp;

-(void) AddAllCompanyCostInformation:(NSNumber *) costTermin
                     withTotalITCost:(NSNumber *) costIT
                   withTotalTeleCost:(NSNumber *) costTele
                  withTotalCleanCost:(NSNumber *) costClean
                     withTotalElCost:(NSNumber *) costEl
                   withTotalSuppCost:(NSNumber *) costSupp
                   withTotalElseCost:(NSNumber *) costElse;


@end
```

Hope someone can help.
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Add all those method signatures to your `CompCost.h`:

```
-(void)setAmountTermin:(NSNumber*)amount;
```

This answer assumes that the method bodies exist in the `CompCost.m` folder...

---

Edit: I'm just noticing that you're trying to call these methods from `CompCost.m`.  If you want these methods as private methods, you need to add them to `CompCost.m` and don't need to add them to `CompCost.h`.

---

> An " No visible @interface for 'CompCost' declares the selector "
>   occurs here logicForCompCost setAmountTermin:costTermin and for the
>   whole segment

Your error is saying "Hey, you're trying to call a method that doesn't exist."  You need to write that method.  `logicForCompCost` is of type `CompCost`.  It needs a visible selector with the names of the methods you're trying to call.  Because we're working in the `CompCost.m` file, you can write a public `@interface` (in the `.h`) or a private `@interface` (in the `.m`) and it will clear this error.  You'll still though need to write the method bodies.

---

Alternatively, if you add these things as `@properties`, you won't have to write the methods.  For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* amountTermin;
```

This creates `amountTermin` as a `@property` (can be public or private, depending on how you do it), and creates a `setAmountTermin` method that takes an `NSNumber*` and assigns it to `amountTermin` and creates a `amountTermin` method that returns `amountTermin` (as `NSNumber*`).  You can also just access `amountTermin` using dot-notation if you use a `@property`.

---

And as one final note... the method in question makes no sense at all... this instance method creates a new object of this type and adds to an array, which is also an instance variable on objects of this type.  You've got some organizational issues here... it's confusing, and will almost certainly lead to trouble eventually...